# can 炎也 and/or 炎羅 be used as a name?

Tags: meaning, names

both with the on'yomi reading, so either enya or enra. i know very little about japanese and am looking for a name for a character i'm making and, after doing a bit of research, thought i liked these. from what i can tell 炎 means flame/blaze, which sorta relates to part of the chaacter. could they be used as names and not seem too weird? and if so what would they both, roughly, mean put together?

Answer (score 3):

It's a little odd and too [chūnibyō](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Chuunibyou)-ish as a real person name. I know no real person whose real name contains the kanji 炎. It may be okay as the name of a male character in a shounen manga or a fantasy work. (炎羅 might be used also as a female name.)

炎 is the only kanji that has a clear meaning. Both 也 and 羅 are basically just "kanji for names" which do not have clear meanings by themselves. (I mean, they did have some original meanings, but they are almost forgotten by laypeople. Similar kanji include 伊 and 圭.) Therefore, if your character is related to fire, it may sound a little too straightforward and facile to native Japanese speakers. Imagine how a character named "Blaze" sounds to native English speakers.

Well, if your character is like the image below, 炎也/炎羅 may be a reasonable choice...

[image] (From 聖闘士星矢Ω)

Comment: 可**也**ええ情報やねん！　笑

Comment: thanks! the story is a bit more fantasy leaning, though i wouldn't say it's a complete fantasy world. probably more like a modern setting with a soft magic system. is 煙 or 焦 any better or is it basically the same as 炎 when it comes to realistic names?